# How to play sound for iOS 8.1 simulators

Tags: xcode6.1, audiotoolbox, ios8.1

In Xcode 6.1 AudioToolbox.framework for sound doesn't work. It works fine on iOS 7 through iOS 7.1 but not any iOS 8.1 simulators whether it's iPhone or iPad. Is this an error with iOS 8.1 sound or does AudioToolbox framework not work on iOS 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the iOS 8.x simulator runtimes.  You should be able to play audio successfully with other APIs, but unfortunately AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() and related functions in AudioToolbox.framework aren't functional.

Comment: I haven't tested my app on actual devices yet. Is this sound bug for iOS 8 only on simulators or actual devices as well for iOS 8?

Comment: It is just a bug in the simulator.